# How to change this queue order?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

now, in my code queue order is

> normal node -> normal node -> item node -> null

front point out normal node, but i want point out item node!

so, i want to change the code order

> item node -> normal node -> normal node -> null

and my code is,,

```
    void LQ_CreateQueue(LinkedQueue **Queue)
{
    (*Queue) = (LinkedQueue*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedQueue));
    (*Queue)->Front = NULL;
    (*Queue)->Rear = NULL;
    (*Queue)->count = 0;
}

Node *LQ_CreateNode(int NewData)
{
    Node *NewNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (NewData == 7) 
        NewNode->Priority = ItemBlock;
    else 
        NewNode->Priority = NormalBlock;

    NewNode->rand_value = NewData;
    NewNode->NextNode = NULL;

    return NewNode;
}

void LQ_DestroyNode(Node *_Node)
{
    free(_Node);
}

void LQ_Enqueue(LinkedQueue *Queue, Node *NewNode)
{
    if (Queue->Front == NULL)
    {
        Queue->Front = NewNode;
        Queue->Rear = NewNode;
        Queue->count++;
    }
    else
    {
        Queue->Rear->NextNode = NewNode;
        Queue->Rear = NewNode;
        Queue->count++;
    }
}

Node *LQ_Dequeue(LinkedQueue *Queue)
{
    Node *Front = Queue->Front;

    if (Queue->Front->NextNode == NULL)
    {
        Queue->Front = NULL;
        Queue->Rear = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Queue->Front = Queue->Front->NextNode;
    }

    Queue->count--;

    return Front;
}

int LQ_IsEmpty(LinkedQueue *Queue)
{
    return (Queue->Front == NULL);
}
```

help me.

this code is consist of CreateQueue, CreateNode, DeleteNode, InsertNode, PrintNode, CheckEmptyQueue function.In order..

how to change that code.?

Comment: Technically that's not a queue anymore if you want a special order of the contents, then it's an ordered list.

Comment: ooops..! that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after reading a little more about your code, what you seem to want is a kind of queue, called *priority queue*. The "secret" to keeping them in order, is when inserting new nodes you walk through the list from the beginning to the end to find the place where to insert the node.

In your case, since you only have two priorities, it's even simpler:

- If inserting a "normal node" then find the last "item node" and insert the "normal node" after the last "item node" (make the new "normal node" `NextNode` pointer equal to the last "item node" `NextNode` pointer (with a simple assignment), then make the last "item node" `NextNode` pointer point to the new "normal node", note that order of operations is important)
- If inserting an "item node" then just add it to the beginning of the queue.

Or some variant of the above.

Comment: oh thank you,. but i know that you tell me.
but.. i don't write the code..
please change code.. please ..